# How to add the quantity corresponding to same number in different sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

Team,

I have the attached sheet where in multiple common materials are used in build up of different equipments.

What I intend to do is to get the sum of  Qty of each material required (Col E )ex-120140970 across all the sheets, compare with the quantity on hand F (which is a constant for that material) and highlight the total shortage so the same can be sourced.

Appreciate your help.

[enter link description here](https://gofile.io/d/S99yxd)

Comment: Which field you want to use for total C2+D2+E2 for 120140970  since F2 & H2 getting values from other Sheet !! Better name the common column you want to use to add across sheets.

Comment: Have edited the post Rajesh.

Comment: Hi @Shiv,, now check my post I've solved the issue, I'm sure this is what you are looking for.☺

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise to explain your requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

*This solves the issue:*

**:Caveat:**

*For better understanding & visualization, I've taken small section of database, you need to workout with real data.*

**Data across sheets:**

[image]

---

**How it works:**

1. On the sheet where you want to get the total, enter Sheet name (from which you want to get Qtys' value to SUM for common parts).

[image]

1. Enter Sheet name as I did in A122:A123.
   Select them and assign a suitable NAME to them.

*Use Name Manager.*

2. Get part's Name in A127:A134.
3. Enter this formula in Cell B127 & fill down.

   ```
   =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!A2:A9"),$A127,INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!D2:D9")))
   ```

*`SheetList`, is the NAME assign to range A122:A123.*

*A2:A9 is range has Parts No, and D2:D9 has Qty values across sheets.*

4. Now apply conditional formatting on the required column since you
   got the SUM.
5. *You may adjust cell references and name of range, in the formula as needed.*